# Get days different between two dates(excluding weekends)

Tags: php, date, mysqli, datediff

I'm trying to get days count between two dates from database. Date_from and Date_to. And I'm getting an error. Any help would be appreciated.
The code:

```
<?php
    require('config/conn.php');

    // Select all from table 'reguests'
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM requests';

    //Results from table
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    //Fetch data
    $requests = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    //Free result from fetch
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    //Get Days Count Between Dates From And To
    $dateFrom = $request['date_from'];
    $dateTo = $requests['date_to'];

    $daysDiff = floor(abs(strtotime($dateTo) - strtotime($dateFrom)) / (60*60*24));


    //Close conn
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Output:

```
<td><?php echo $daysDiff ?>
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799513/count-weekends-between-2-dates)

Comment: I would use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title says to exclude weekends, but your code doesn't seem to try to?

To account for more complicated logic like that it's probably prudent to calculate a period and use it to iterate over days.

Something like this:

```php
$dateFrom = new DateTime();
$dateTo   = new DateTime( '+1 month +1 second' ); // Add 1s so period includes last day.

$period   = new DatePeriod( $dateFrom, new DateInterval( 'P1D' ), $dateTo );
$days     = 0;

foreach ( $period as $date ) {

    $day = $date->format( 'l' );

    if ( 'Saturday' !== $day && 'Sunday' !== $day ) {
        $days ++;
    }
}

echo $days; // 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review your title, it's ambiguous with your problem. But to check difference between dates, please check the Php manual on the link: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

If you really wanna check if a day is weekend, please check: [Checking if date is weekend PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php)